# jQuery post cannot get $_POST in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I have a form with an `onkeyup` event.
I try to send a variable to my php script and show result in a div.

Thanks to this forum I got my test function to half work:

```
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
```

If I continue with:
1) `jQuery("#theForm").serialize(),`
I get response text which is "Hello World"
If I try to pass a variable:
2) `{ name: "p" },`
I get: -1

JavaScript

```
function submit_me(){
jQuery.post(
    the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, 
    { name: "p" },
function(response_from_the_action_function){
    jQuery("#txtHint").html(response_from_the_action_function);
    }
);
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
function the_action_function(){
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Hello World, " . $name;
die();
}
?>
```

FORM

```
<form id="theForm">
 <input type="text" name="user">
 <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook">
 <input id="submit_button" value = "Click This" type="button" onkeyup="submit_me()">
<form>
```

I actually want `onkeyup="submit_me(this.value, 0)"`
I am doing this on a WordPress through their admin-ajax.php file.

Where is the problem in this?

EDIT

Apparently I had to add action to data

```
{ action:'the_ajax_hook', name:"p" }
```

I guess its WP requirement, rather than jQuery, because I saw examples as this:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }
```

everywhere.

Comment: Why do you have die() at the end of your php script?

Comment: Also, you don't need the function around the PHP code. It's probably not getting called when the PHP script is running.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#my_form").submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault() // to prevent natural form submit action
                    $.post(
                        "processing.php",
                        { name: "p" },
                        function(data) {
                             var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                             $("#txtHint").html(response.hello_world);
                        }
                    );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="my_form" action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user" />
            <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook" />
            <input type="button" name="submit" value = "Click This" />
        </form>
        <div id="txtHint"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then in processing.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $response['hello_world'] = "Hello World, " . $name;
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```